# A time based function throttler in Golang

Tags: go, throttling

My use case is: when user stops typing in the text box, I will call a function `process_input()`, I can't call it on every character, I need to only call it after the typing is finished.

So the idea is: use a helper function to throttle the `process_input()`, if it is called repeatedly within a period of time, the previous calls will be discarded, only the last call will be triggered after a while.

I want to use it like:

```golang
func process_input() {
    fmt.Println(`process_input() called`)
}

func main() {
    fn := buffer.Timed(time.Second, process_input)
    fn() // shouldn't be called
    fn() // may be called or not
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fn() // shouldn't be called
    fn() // will be called

    time.Sleep(time.Hour) // block it from exiting
}
```

My implementation:

```golang
package buffer

import (
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func Timed(dur time.Duration, fn func()) func() {

    kill := make(chan bool)

    isScheduled := atomic.Bool{}

    return func() {
        if isScheduled.Load() { // if there is previous job scheduled
            kill <- true // kill the previous, sometimes this line causes deadlock.
        }

        // start the next
        isScheduled.Store(true)

        go func() {
            defer isScheduled.Store(false)

            select {
            case <-time.After(dur):
                go fn()
            case <-kill:
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

Sometimes it crashes with deadlock at the line `kill <- true`, how to fix it?

Comment: You are actually describing *debouncing* rather than *throttling*.

Comment: When the second call to `fn()` in `main()` runs `kill <- true`, what follows is a race between `isScheduled.Store(true)` and `isScheduled.Store(false)`. If `false` wins, the third call to `fn()` will spawn a second go routine without ending the first. If `true` wins, the third call to `fn()` has `if isScheduled.Load()` racing with the previous go routine: as intended, `go fn()` may or may not be called. However, if `isScheduled.Store(false)` is run after `if isScheduled.Load()` is evaluated, the code will then attempt to write into your unbuffered channel while no other goroutines are active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a number of logical errors dealing with synchronization, but you can avoid most of the complications by reducing the concurrency and just using a timer to trigger the function for you.

Your goal (at least as it appears in the code above) is to have the function triggered after a delay, and reset that delay on each new call *if* the function has not yet been called. You can do this with a single [`time.Timer`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Timer) and a mutex to protect the field: https://go.dev/play/p/54QMJ7xHTZ5

```
func NewDebouncer(dur time.Duration) func(fn func()) {
    d := &debouncer{
        dur: dur,
    }

    return func(fn func()) {
        d.reset(fn)
    }
}

type debouncer struct {
    mu    sync.Mutex
    dur   time.Duration
    delay *time.Timer
}

func (d *debouncer) reset(fn func()) {
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()

    if d.delay != nil {
        d.delay.Stop() {
    }

    d.delay = time.AfterFunc(d.dur, fn)
}
```

An example with multiple calls would look like:

```
process_input := func(i int) func() {
    return func() {
        fmt.Printf("process_input() %d called\n", i)
    }
}

fn := NewDebouncer(time.Second)
fn(process_input(0))
fn(process_input(1))
fn(process_input(2))
fn(process_input(3))

time.Sleep(1100 * time.Millisecond)
fn(process_input(4))
fn(process_input(5))
fn(process_input(6))

// output:
// process_input() 3 called
// process_input() 6 called
```